# SSH proxy laptop

Tags: ssh, proxy, arch-linux, laptop

I run a simple ssh proxy and I am always on the move with my laptop. Having to restart it every time I open the lid and connect to the internet.

```
sshpass -p password ssh -D 9999 root@myvpsip
```

Is it possible to have it start when my internet does then stop when the internet connection is terminated?

```
Network Manger
Cinnamon DE
Arch Linux x64
```

Comment: Well it sounds like it already does "stop when the internet connection is terminated". Can just put a script in `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d` to start it up.

Answer (score 2):

Two generic recommendations first:

- Start by configuring a regular user account `@myvpsip` instead of using root.
- Set up public key based authentication for that account so you don't need to mess about with plain text passwords in your ssh scripts.

From the NetworkManager manual page:

> NetworkManager will execute scripts in the
>   /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d directory in alphabetical order in
>   response to network events. Each script should be (a) a regular file,
>   (b) owned by root, (c) not writable by group or other, (d) not
>   set-uid, (e) and executable by the owner. Each script receives two
>   arguments, the first being the interface name of the device just
>   activated, and second an action.

So yes, it seems you can trigger actions from NetworkManager on the start and stop of network connections.

A simple script may be (untested):

```
#!/bin/bash
#/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/ssh-proxy

case "$2" in
  up)
    nohup ssh -D 9999 user@myvpsip 
    tunnelpid=$!
    echo $tunnelpid > /var/run/ssh-proxy
    ;;
  down)
    if [ -e /var/run/ssh-proxy ] ; then
    tunnelpid=$(cat /var/run/ssh-proxy) 
    kill -9 $tunnelpid
    rm /var/run/ssh-proxy
    fi
    ;;
esac
```